# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on for loop (array function pointer)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

The following code is causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS address 0x0 error - even when i is correct somehow. It's used to execute the arrays pointed to the functions. If I change the `sizeof(draw);` with the number i have, it just works as expected.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(draw); i++)
        draw[i](i);
```

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(draw)` returns the size of "draw" in number of bytes, not number of items. You are probably looking for `(sizeof(draw)/sizeof(draw[0]))`

Comment: This won't work correctly if `draw` is actually a pointer that has been the product of an array being decayed.  Better to use `std::array` and drop the raw array usage, since `std::array` has `size()` to determine the number of elements, and will not decay to a pointer when passed.